# Contradicting results by choosing different layers/nodes

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning

I'm new with NN, and learn that I have to experiment out my way to decide what # of lays/nodes to use to fit the model. However, could it happen that model outputs based on different layers/nodes choices occur to be contradicting from each other, but hard to tell who's right and who's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Deciding on the structure of your NN is one of the most difficult things to do and you will most likely not get the perfect structure, unless you want to spend weeks figuring it out ofcourse. When comparing different NN's with eachother you're not only comparing the different structures but also the first random initialisation of the weights. NN1 gets assigned different random weights compared to NN2.

In my experience it's best practice to gridsearch over some combinations of nodes and layers and then crossvalidate the results. After deciding which combination worked best compare the results of your CV and the performance of the model on the test set. If the results differ significantly you should re-evaluate if you are either under or over fitting and adjust your model accordingly.